# JQuery inverse row column's on event

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to inverse two columns position when an event come, the right be the left and Vice versa;

```
  <div class="row">
          <div class="col-6 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center ">
            <div class="logo-centered" id="logo_auth">
              <a href="#default">
                <img src="assets/img/baladiaty-t.svg" alt="logo">
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-6 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
            <div class="v1-slogan" id="v1_slogan">
              <h3>Spécial covid-19</h3>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

---

```
.logo-centered{
  width: auto !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since a Bootstrap row uses flexbox for layout, you can take advantage of flebox's `order` property to swap the order of the columns. In fact, [Bootstrap provides order classes that you can add to the elements](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#order-classes).

It's not clear how the event you want to trigger the reordering is listened to, but basically in the event listener's callback you can simply add the class `order-1` to the column you want to appear first, and then `order-2` to the one that should appear second.

See proof-of-concept example below, using the markup you've provided. You can click on the button to swap the order:

```js
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.getElementById('logo-col').classList.toggle('order-2');
  document.getElementById('slogan-col').classList.toggle('order-1');
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn">Click to swap column order</button>
<br /><br />
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-6 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center" id="logo-col">
    <div class="logo-centered" id="logo_auth">
      <a href="#default">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x100?text=Logo" alt="logo">
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center" id="slogan-col">
    <div class="v1-slogan" id="v1_slogan">
      <h3>Spécial covid-19</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```